# Network manager applet in Gnome 3 .1X disappears when connected to the Internet

Tags: network-manager, indicator, ubuntu-gnome

When using a wired connction to connect with the Internet, the network manager applet in the system status(tray) disappears. It comes back when the wired connection is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. This a new feature introduced in Gnome 3.10.
The new design aims to keep the status area simple & clean.

> Wired connection is indicated, only if you get disconnected from the network.

[See the design plan](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Design/Guidelines/SystemStatus/)